# printout statement in while loop execution in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have one question on printout instruction in while loop. The sample code would be like.

```
int main() {
    bool flag=true;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(flag) {
        cout << ". ";
        for (long i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
             for (long j = 0; j < 100000; ++j) ;
        if (++cnt > 10) flag = false;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

What I expect is that, the '.' would show in the console each after each during the execution. But the experiment shows as, all these dots would appear at the same time, which in my understanding is after the whole execution, these dots would be printout to the console.

could anyone help me explain this? Whether I am wrong that these are actually show one after another during the execution and only because the execution speed? Or this is the issue, that everything is cached until the while loop finished.

I run this in GDB step by step, it does execute the line during loop execution.

Comment: Are you sure your nested for loops are even executing? I would expect them to be completely optimized away, since they don't do anything, and any delay when you start your program is just the program loading and starting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cout is buffered.  Use

```
cout << ". " << flush;
```

to get the char all the way out to the console one at a time.

Comment: thank you so much for quick answer. I have another question is, why cout can be out to the console immediately when outside of the while loop?